# Is there anyway to know when the Share Model of the iOS will be presented or dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know if iOS provides us any way to know when the Share Modal will be presented or dismissed.

Comment: Present and dismiss view controller functions both have a completion handler do they not?

Comment: When you present an UIViewController of any kind, you can optionally add a completion block when it finishes presenting. [Apple Docs ref](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present).

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! Do you mind posting your answers with an example, so I can set it as the correct answer, please? Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var completionWithItemsHandler: UIActivityViewController.CompletionWithItemsHandler? { get set }
```

The completion handler to execute after the activity view controller is dismissed.

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItems], applicationActivities: nil)
activity.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    // dismiss activity
}
self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Presents a view controller modally.

**completion**

```
self.present(activity, animated: true) {

}
```

The block to execute after the presentation finishes. This block has no return value and takes no parameters. You may specify nil for this parameter.